# PHP - Verificar todas as datas dos recorda dos utilizadores

Tags: php

Boas,

EU criei um script que o objetivo é determinar se as Datas da Coluna ads_featured_dates estão expiradas ou não....

O problema é que, o script faz update as que passaram da data, mas também as que ainda não passaram...

Como resolvo?

```
function check_promotions_date($con) {

  $search_expire_dates = "SELECT ads_featured_date, ads_featured, ads_id 
  FROM public_ads WHERE ads_featured = 1";
  $expire_query = $con->query($search_expire_dates);  

  while($expire_details = $expire_query->fetch_assoc()) {

  $todays_date = date("Y-m-d"); 
  $reset_days = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";       

  if($todays_date > $expire_details['ads_featured_date']) {

      $update_dates = "UPDATE public_ads SET ads_featured_date = '$reset_days', ads_featured = 0";
      $query_updated = $con->query($update_dates);
  } 

 }
```

}

Comment: Eu alterei assim o update... UPDATE public_ads SET ads_featured_date = '$reset_days', ads_featured = 0 WHERE NOW() > ads_featured_date";

Comment: Será que o NOW() > ads_featured_date resultará?

Comment: Precisa fazer isso com PHP? Por quê não faz direto com SQL tudo?

Comment: Como assim????»

Comment: Mostre uma ideia dessa função que faça o que pretendo..

Comment: Apenas se conseguir descrever melhor o que pretende fazer e apresentar as estruturas das tabelas. Aliás, onde está o `where` do seu *update*? Sem ele, dependendo da configuração do banco, você atualizará sempre toda a tabela.